# Show remote shares in Network

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I've just got a brand new Windows 10 machine. I can't see any of my existing shares from my other machines in `Network`, but if I type the address in manually `\\computer-name\path\to\share` it comes up straight away. However, the name still doesn't appear in `Network`. I have a much older machine also running Windows 10 (the same version) and it shows all the shares by default.

How can I get Windows 10 to show the available shares in `Network` so I can browse them?

The network connection has the following set:

- Private
- Turn on network discovery
- Turn on automatic setup of network connected devices.

Comment: Is the new computer using the network as `Private` instead of `Public`? You can check this in start, settings, network, and on the active connection it will say one or the other.

Comment: @shawn Yes, but I thought the other one was too.